# window.open URL with uid contains

Tags: url, href, window.open, userid

I am a complete newbie

I would like to create a script which should execute the following.

1: starts in the mailbox " www.****.com/mailview".

click the first link that contains "userid=4374856" (it will open a new tab)

2: In the new tab, after 30sec, click a link that contains "/mailcheck.php?". (a new tab will open)

3: after another 90sec both tabs should be closed, so that I am back on my start page "mailviewer".

4: The page I should make a reload and the script should start again.

endless loop

Comment: could you further explain what you are trying to achieve please?

Comment: I would like to create a script which should execute the following.

1: starts in the mailbox " www.****.com/mailview".
click the first link that contains "userid=4374856" (it will open a new tab)
2: In the new tab, after 30sec, click a link that contains "/mailcheck.php?". (a new tab will open)
3: after another 90sec both tabs should be closed, so that I am back on my start page "mailviewer".
4: The page I should make a reload and the script should start again.

endless loop

Comment: what have you tried? And I suggest using selenium for this.

Comment: i have built a basic framework with some commands, like for example

(function() {
    'use strict';
if(location.pathname.match('mailviewer') !== null) { //start the if condition only if the currently opened tab is http://www.*******.com/mailviewer
setTimeout(function(){ //Start executing the following codes after the timeout....

window.open('??????????', '_blank');
}, 3000);
}


but I don't know how to include the link which is always different but contains a fixed userid in the window.open

Comment: You could look for a string in a url? Other than that your question needs more clarity.